# Superglobals can't be accessed via variable variables in a function?

Tags: php

I can't access superglobals via variable variables inside a function. Am I the source of the problem or is it one of PHP's subtleties? And how to bypass it?

```
print_r(${'_GET'});
```

works fine

```
$g_var = '_GET';
print_r(${$g_var});
```

Gives me a Notice: Undefined variable: _GET

Comment: (related)[variable variables with PHP's Superglobal arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58832360/6521116)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PHP isn't able to recognize that this is a global variable access:
It compiles `$_GET` and `${'_GET'}` to the same opcode sequence, namely a `global` `FETCH_R`. `${$g_var}` on the other hand will result in a `local` `FETCH_R`.

This is also mentioned in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php#refsect1-language.variables.superglobals-notes):

> Superglobals cannot be used as variable variables inside functions or class methods.

Comment: Although if you include `global ${$g_var}` inside the function (as you would need to do for any _ordinary_ global variable) then appears to work OK? Is this a viable workaround, or are there other caveats?

Answer (score 2):

You can possibly bypass it  using `$GLOBALS` superglobal variable. Instead of writing

```
function & getSuperGlobal($name) {
    return ${"_$name"};
}
```

you can write

```
function & getSuperGlobal($name) {
    return $GLOBALS["_$name"];
}
```

and the results will equal.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the last PHP versions are dealing fine with that problem.
Next code works fine with PHP 5.5.9.

```
<?php

function foo() {
  print_r(${'_SERVER'});
}

foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, according to the docs [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) on variable variables, they cannot be used on superglobals inside functions or class methods:

> Warning
>
> Please note that variable variables cannot be used with PHP's Superglobal arrays within functions or class methods. The variable $this is also a special variable that cannot be referenced dynamically.

You can simply get around that by declaring them as global variables or referencing them through $GLOBALS variable

Example:

```
<?php
    function myFunc ($varname) {
        global $$varname;
        var_dump($$varname);
    }
    myFunc('_SERVER'); // works
    myFunc('_POST'); // works


    function mySecondFunc ($varname) {
        var_dump($GLOBALS[$varname]);
    }
    mySEcondFunc('_SERVER'); // works
    mySecondFunc('_POST'); // works
```

Note: these do not work for $_ENV!