# PHP Variable Variable Request Method

Tags: php, request, variable-variables

I'm working on a web library for personal use.  I thought I'd be all clever and use variable variables to make my library support all request methods easily.

I had:

```
$request = '_' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$request = $$request;
```

But I get:

> Undefined variable: _POST

Printed to my php error log.

I was just curious as to whether my idea is flawed conceptially, as well as why the logic fails to work when the following does:

```
$_a = 'b';
$b = '_a';
$c = $$b;
```

**Edit:**

The following does work:

```
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ? $_POST : $_GET;
```

**Duplicate of:**
[Superglobals can't be accessed via variable variables in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071118/superglobals-cant-be-accessed-via-variable-variables-in-a-function)

To fix I did:

```
$request = $GLOBALS['_' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']];
```

You could also use my original code outside of a function or class.

Comment: Why do you use ninja code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Superglobals can't be accessed via variable variables in a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8071118/1503018)

Comment: @VeeeneX I was using this code to support multiple request methods.  Primarily GET and POST, I don't know that this would work for PATCH/PUT/DELETE, etc.  Note my recent answer which probably  is a better way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To made it work as I said in my post:**

> $request = $GLOBALS['_' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']];

**Why?**

Because $_POST and $_GET are global variables and need to accessed as such.  Inside functions/classes you would usually do something like:

```
global $_POST;
```

before using.

You could also use the original code outside of a function or class.

**Better way in this case?**

My intention with this was to support multiple request methods.  I don't thing that this would work for PUT/PATCH/DELETE etc.  I would advise instead you use:

```
$requestdata = fopen("php://input", "r");
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php

This may not work for url parameters only request body.  Not sure.  (If this is the case then for get REQUESTS you'd want to use $_GET

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are getting is correct, there is no such variable as $_POST.

```
$request = '_' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

Let's assume $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] is "POST" which it will be for an HTTP POST request.

Therefore $request == "_POST"

```
$request = $$request;
```

i.e. `$request = $_POST;`

What is it exactly you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: @deltababel The reason I was doing this magically was so the server worked for multiple request methods.  Ex. get and post