# Trying to access $_SERVER(or any global) variable from string name

Tags: php, variables, global-variables, variable-variables

Today I met such a terrible situation.
It seems this bug is related to `PHP`.

I'm trying to access to `$_SERVER` or another super global variables but from string name.

#### This version of implementation is working.

```php
var_dump(${"_SERVER"}); // working
```

#### But when trying to do this with variable then receiving notice that variable not found.

```php
$var_name = "_SERVER";
var_dump(${$var_name}); // Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: _SERVER in...
```

> And this will happen only with a global variable.

What is going on there? Can someone explain this situation.

Comment: Did you search for soultion. As i can see, it's working

Comment: Works for me: https://3v4l.org/LPTSv

Comment: Works for me too

Comment: It not works for me. It output `null` when use `var_dump(${$var_name})`, but output everything of the session when use `var_dump($_SERSION)`

Comment: Why that complicated? Simply use `$_SERVER[$key]`.

Comment: @NigelRen you may as well still close it so that there's a reference link...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

variable variables cannot be used with PHP's Superglobal arrays within functions or class methods. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/QF6Km)

Refer to [php doc Variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

> Please note that variable variables cannot be used with PHP's
>   Superglobal arrays within functions or class methods. The variable
>   $this is also a special variable that cannot be referenced
>   dynamically.